# Conditions of convergence of convex optimization

Tags: optimization, convergence

The problem description is here:

[image]

Comment: That doesn't really work either. In any case, I suspect this question would work better on mathoverflow or cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Since your problem is convex, bounded from below, and contain no additional constraints, a local optima is global, an can be found at a stationary point; namely where the gradient of your function is zero. Look into "sufficient conditions of local optimality": since you've already shown that the gradient converges to zero, the result of should follow.

Comment: @dfri As I have said in the question, if we assume the optimum point of convex function is attainable, namely this point is not infinity,  then we can have F approaches infimum when |g| approaches 0. But considering f(x) = exp(-x) for example, you will see the hard core of this question.

Comment: @harold Thanks, I have posted this question on cs.stackexchange.com, unfortunately, I have not received an answer yet. What do you mean "doesn't really work"? Do you mean we can not have f(x_k) approaching the Inf of f(x) given the gradient g(x_k) approaching zero in general?

Comment: @user5694458 I meant the format, as a picture, well I guess it kind of works but it's not how it's supposed to be done. I can't find the question there by the way

Comment: @harold Sorry, I posted it on scicomp.stackexchange.com (http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/21607/conditions-of-convergence-of-convex-optimization). The  scicomp.stackexchange.com supports latex format. It seems that stack overflow  doesn't support latex. Therefore, I post it as a picture to keep the formula.